# на прозрачной панели, непрозрачная кнопка нужна

Tags: java, javafx

у меня полу прозрачная панель, если я кидаю на нее лейбл, он тоже становится прозрачным, хотя на лейбле стоит прозрачность в 1, как сделать так, чтобы лейбл не был прозрачным, а сама панель была прозрачной?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы используете сцен билдер, то просто "поменяйте местами" отрисовку. Другими словами, лейбл должен рисоваться последним, и быть последним в списке.

Comment: спасибо, я чет не подумал, надо было сначал елйбл ставить, а потом уже саму панель, просто если именно как вы говорите сделать, он все равно на панели будет, но все же спасибо